# How to detect block level changes in a file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

How I may know which file is modified and what data is changed in the file?

Edit: I want to watch the file as it gets modified and then compare it against a previous version to know which data blocks are changed. I guess watching the file for changes can be accomplished by using file watcher API but I have no idea about the second part.

Comment: to clarify: Do you want to watch the filesystem for changes or do you want to compare two versions of a file against each other.

Comment: Actually I want to do both. Edited my question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You may need the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is define [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), subscribe to its events and process them accordingly to the logic of your application.

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mokhtarb2005/FSWatcherMB12052005063103AM/FSWatcherMB.aspx) is a simple example.